# Twilio: Get parameters from outbound calls from recordings

Tags: twilio

I have a TwiMl like this in a Bin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say voice="alice">Hello {{Name}}. You have ticket number {{TicketNum}} so please solve it.</Say>
</Response>
```

Then I use hmac authentication and launch the script to make the call using the following TWIML Bin url with query strings attached:
    twiml_link="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EHxxxxxxxxxxx?Name=Bob&TicketNum=45"

I get the call with Bob and Ticket 45. After that I need to alert our incident tracking system that Bob has acknowledge the ticket 45 and is "on it." I can't because of architecture send something back to my system. I need to go out and query twilio again.

So I wrote this python snippet to hit the Twilio API to find all completed calls. :

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import sys, os

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

calls = client.calls.list(status=completed)

for call in calls:
    print(call.sid)
    print(call.to)
    print(call.status)
    print(call.start_time)
    print(call.duration)
    print(call.annotation)
    print(call.uri)
```

None of these commands can print Bob or the ticket number or the Twiml Bin URL or the query strings I used. Any tips? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I think Alan might have the best idea at the end of his answer. If you can redirect to a Twilio Function once the `<Say>` completes, including the parameters from the call in the URL, then you could record the details somehow in the Function. The API is not going to save parameters that you pass to the TwiMLBin.

Answer (score 1):

That approach isn't a reliable way to determine if the intended party answered the phone and acknowledge the message without "Human Detection". You can find more details here.

Alternative to AMD - "Human Detection"
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223132567-Can-Twilio-tell-whether-a-call-was-answered-by-a-human-or-machine-#alternatives-to-amd

The dialed party could be a voicemail system, so querying the REST API to see if the call status was completed will provide misleading results if your goal is to determine the person acknowledged the ticket.

You could use a Twilio Function, https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007737928-Building-apps-with-Twilio-Functions, to collect the result of the

Alan